# Android studio is showing " Installation did not succeed" during installation in physical device

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am developing an application in Android Studio with Java. My app is running fine in the android studio emulator. But when i connected a physical device and wanted to install my app that it showed:

**10/28 14:23:49: Launching 'app' on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8.**
**Installation did not succeed.**
**The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED**

**List of apks:
[0] 'E:\Project 250\3rdEye\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk'
Installation failed due to: 'null'**

I have tried changing the run configuration and installing `-r -t` flags but still, it doesn't work. Can someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think is not support Xiaomi Redmi Note 8, Please watch youtube